# How to get File value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to upload an image from HTML and I'm using a javascript function to detect a change in the image and then send it to php function to upload. My function is working in chrome, firefox, IE 10, but it doesn't work in IE9 or older because file API is not supported.

Is any alternative to send the file that work in IE9?

My Javascript

```
if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
    }

var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        file = this.files[i];
        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            if ( window.FileReader ) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                    showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("images[]", file);
            }
        }   
    }

    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some URL",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res; 
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm looking another way to get the file value and sent it in the variable formdata.

Thanks

Comment: In IE9 and below you'll need a hidden iframe to submit the file, as IE doesn't support formData or the File API

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you give me an example of how could I get the file using the iframe?